# Help with Receptacle Inside Cabinet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

[image]

I'm trying to create a giant medicine cabinet here on this wall, and hoping to put a receptacle on the inside of it.  I don't want wires to channel inside of the cabinet itself.  Right now, I have a receptacle to the left of the stud.  What are my options?  Located in USA, Nevada.  THanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You might want to take our tour to familiarize yourself with how the site operates.

Comment: Anything you do something "creative" like that, make sure to arrange it so the GFCI protection is *before* the creative stuff.  That way, your "creative" wiring is inside the zone of GFCI protection, so it will protect you from any wiring that is sub-par.  That is, you should not be feeding a GFCI recep inside the cabinet, but a GFCI somewhere else e.g. Breaker or that other junction box.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this on the medicine cabinet I installed in my bathroom. The issue I think you are going to face is the depth of the wall - at least looking at the picture. I mounted a box on the side of the cabinet in mine but I had a full-depth wall. In your case I would tap into one of your 20 amp GFI protected outlets next to the cabinet using BX cable. Put a knockout in the side of the cabinet. Connect into the cabinet with a BX connector. For the receptacle I would use a narrow, grounded power strip mounting it on the back of the cabinet hard-wired with the BX cable.
I checked in my area and this met code when I used an outlet box. I'm not sure about hard-wiring a power strip but I'm sure one of the electrical experts here on Stack Exchange will educate us.
**Edit**
[image]
Here is one sample of a hard-wired power strip from Amazon. There are others available.

Comment: The depth of the cabinet is about 4 inches, so not much room at all.  Just enough to fit the wifey's beauty products (it's never enough).

When you say put a knockout on the side of the cabinet, you mean put a knockout through that stud?  Can you also give an example of an appropriate grounded power strip I can use?  Hard to visualize all this.  Thanks!

Comment: I mean the depth of the wall. Might be the angle of the pic but do you have 4" depth there?

Comment: You'll have to drill through the stud. You can then run either BX (metalic cable) or NM (Romex) 12/2 w/ground through the stud using the proper connector for BX or NM as it enters the knockout in the cabinet. This can be through the side or the bottom of the cabinet. See edit above for example of a power strip.  **Again, as I mentioned above make sure that the line your tapping into is GFI protected.**